# Carbon Date M-y convert to Y-m?

Tags: php-carbon

I have a string "May-20". Is it possible to use Carbon Library to convert the date as "2020-05"?
Any function can covert it?

```
$date = new DateTime('Aug-20');
echo $date->format('Y-m');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the native method of PHP `createFromFormat()`:

```
Carbon::createFromFormat('!M-y', 'Aug-20')
```

See the list of available format here:
https://www.php.net/manual/fr/datetime.format.php

If your string can be in non-English languages, see the Carbon method `translateTimeString`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$carbon_date = new Carbon('Aug-20');
echo $carbon_date->format("Y-m");
```

Same in one line

```
echo (new Carbon('Aug-20'))->format("Y-m");
```

Comment: Result will be : 2020-08-20 00:00:00.0

Comment: I hope it helped